# Python: Decorator which return other decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have 2 classes used as decorators

```
class A:
    """This is a decorator"""
    pass

class B:
    """This is also a decorator"""
    pass
```

And a third class which I'd like to return either A or either B

```
class C:
    def a(func):
        return A

    def b(func):
        return B


@C.a
def some_func(some_arg):
    pass

@C.b
def other_func(some_arg):
    pass
```

Is it possible such this, and if so how to implement it?

UPDATE:
The problem is that when creating decorator '**call**' is executed during creating. I want to access some configurations, which are set later. So I basically what I'm trying to do is to return wrapper, which return wrapper.

```
class C:
    def __call__(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
             # Do something with global data
             return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

Comment: It's python, almost anything is possible in one way or another. What is wrong with the way you have written it here?

Comment: Just from looking at it, it seems like you just need to use `@C.a()` instead of `@C.a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your exact code to work, all you need to do is change your methods to attributes:

```
class C:
    a = A
    b = B
```

It is questionable whether this is a good idea, though. If you want to have a decorator that does one of two different things, a second-order-decorator (i.e. a function returning a decorator) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work by changing class C to work like this.

```
class C:
    def a(func):
        return A(func)
```

It really boils down to understanding that a decorator is just a syntactic shortcut.

```
@dec
def f():
    pass
```

is exactly the same as:

```
def f():
    pass
f = dec(f)
```